# Why am I getting a vertical line on toolstrip?

Tags: c++, winforms, toolstrip

I have two Windows Forms toolstrips that contain some controls on a form. However, for some strange reason, they contain a vertical line on the right hand side. I cannot find any property to remove them and I cannot find any other information on how to get rid of them online.

[image: Problem illustration]

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the border of the toolstrip.  Meant to give a clear separation between multiple adjacent tool strips.  Changing its RenderMode property to System would be one way to get rid of it, albeit that this changes the look-and-feel.  Or you can write your own renderer to get rid of it.  A C# example:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        toolStrip1.Renderer = new MyRenderer();
    }
    private class MyRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
        protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
```

Comment: It has been a feature for the past 9 years, it will be for the next 9.  Changing it with a single line of code is not called "problem".