# How to override toolstrip renderer?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli, toolstrip

I am new to visual studio and c++, I have created a new CLR Empty Project and have started adding some controls. I notice this strange artefact on the right edge of the toolstrip and would like to remove it.

This question [Why am I getting a vertical line on toolstrip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885780/why-am-i-getting-a-vertical-line-on-toolstrip/11889139#11889139) provides a solution in c# but I am having trouble trying to make it work in visual c++.

First i made new .cpp file called `CustomerRenderer.cpp` and the code looks like this:

```
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

private ref class CustomRenderer : ToolStripRenderer
{
protected:
    virtual void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs^ e) override
    {
        ToolStripRenderer::OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
    }
};
```

Then on my forms load I put this:

```
private: System::Void MainForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        this->toolStrip1->Renderer = gcnew CustomRenderer();
    }
```

And this just makes the toolstrip disappear completely rather than fix the edge artefact. I like the style of the gradient toolstrip so would rather not change to the system renderer.

How can I override the toolstrip renderer in a visual c++ project and remove the edge border artefact?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved by changing:

```
private ref class CustomRenderer : ToolStripRenderer
```

to

```
private ref class CustomRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
```